# Is there a way to get intracluster distances for k-means in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

Hi I am new to Python and trying to figure out these below. Really appreciate any help. Thank you

1. How to get intracluster and intercluster distances in kmeans using python?
2. How to verify the quality of clusters? Any measures to check the goodness of clusters formed?
3. Is there a way to find out which factors/variables are most significant features affecting the clustering - Feature Extraction/Selection

I tried this for question 1 above, is this correct approach??

```
dists = euclidean_distances(km.cluster_centers_)
tri_dists = dists[np.triu_indices(4, 1)]
max_dist, avg_dist, min_dist = tri_dists.max(), tri_dists.mean(), tri_dists.min()

print(max_dist, avg_dist, min_dist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid putting multiple questions into one.

1. K-means does not compute all these distances. Otherwise it would need O(n²) time and memory, that would be much slower! It uses a special property of variance (another reason why it does not just optimize other distances except sum-of-squares) known as the Koenig-Huygens theorem.
2. Yes, there have been over 20, probably even 100, such quality measures proposed in literature. But that does not make it much easier to pick the "best" clustering: in the end, clusters are *subjective* for the user.
3. Yes, you can apply various techniques ranging from variance analysis to factor analysis to random forests.